# django-notification. How can I use threading email send?

Tags: django, django-notification

In my django application I am using `django-notification` to send notifications. However I noticed that in some cases (when sending multiple notifications) my web application is giving delayed responses. Although I am sending notifications through Ajax requests, I still think it would be best if I could implement `mailtools` library which provide threaded emails.

Has anyone implemented such a thing? Is it easy? How can I use `ThreadedMailer` from `mailtools` in `django-notification`?

or, is there another alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) for this purpose. It's easy to setup with django and you can use the code you're using right now.

The ajax request puts the email into task queue and returns. You could return your task id if you want to check later if the task succeeded.

**Update:**

Celery only enables you to call your functions in backgound. Say in ajax view you called:

```
send_email(…)
```

Now in `tasks.py` you should define function:

```
@task
def send_email(…)
```

And in the view you will call it by:

```
send_email.delay(…)
```

And that's it. The email will be sent by background worker deamon using your existing python code.

This doesn't make `django-notification` obsolete. Celery does completly different thing and can be used with any lib you can imagine.

The only change is task arguments have to be pickable. It means you have to pass db ids, not whole objects, etc.

Comment: That is nice, thanks. Does Celery make `django-notification` obsolete? Do all email actions get queued in Celery, automatically? (or they need to be in ajax requests?)

Comment: That is amazing! One last thing. I guess in `def send_mail()` I add `notification.send(args)` and that's it?

Comment: I believe you're right. I've never used `django-notification`, but I use Celery on every day basis to process hundreds of tasks.